# OnTransitionEnd isn't getting called in React

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, styled-components, handler

I'm building a carousel and I have my render components looking like this:

```
<CarouselWrapper>
      <Carousel3D style={rotationStyle} />
</CarouselWrapper>
```

with styling

```
export const CarouselWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 2000px; 

export const Carousel3D = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
`
```

When I press an arrow key, I update `rotationStyle` to be `` {transform : `rotateY( ${angle}deg)`} `` of some angle I calculate.

This works fine. The carousel successfully rotates (taking 1s to do so). However, I want to do something once the rotation stops. I tried adding `onTransitionEnd` like so:

```
<Carousel3D style={rotationStyle} 
        onTransitionEnd={(ev:any) => handleTransitionEnd(ev)}>
```

and having the handler log to console:

```
const handleTransitionEnd = (ev : any) => {
    console.log('ended');
}
```

but nothing ever shows. I also tried passing `onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}` instead. I'm using functional components, if that helps to know.

How come my `onTransitionEnd` never gets called?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, you but you didn't show how you handle the key action. I think the problem is there. I reproduced your code, maybe you can find it where needs to fixed it.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const CarouselWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 2000px;
`;

export const Carousel3D = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
`;

export default function App() {
  const [log, setLog] = useState("press left, right arrow key");

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "ArrowLeft" || event.key === "ArrowRight") {
        setLog("key pressed");
      }
    });

    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", () => {});
  }, []);

  const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
    setLog("transition ended");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CarouselWrapper>
        <Carousel3D
          style={{
            transform: `rotateY(${log === "key pressed" ? "100" : "0"}deg)`
          }}
          onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
        />
        {log}
      </CarouselWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: Hi, my key action works fine (I've tested it with console logging and other behavior) and it's how you did it essentially. The only difference is I do ```setRotationStyle({transform : `rotateY( ${angle}deg)`});``` where `angle = (++selectedIndex / cards.length * -360)`. This makes the carousel rotate.

Comment: @Elliptica Try to create `const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(0)` for **angle** value, then put **angle** (calculated) value in state, use inline style (remove setRotationStyle function), it will look like ``style={{transform : `rotateY( ${angle}deg)`}}``